# Why is my Linq to Entities command causing a stack overflow?

Tags: linq-to-entities, stack-overflow

I have the following code:

```
public List<NoteViewModel> GetAllPerContacts(List<long> contactIds)
{
    // This next line causes a stack overflow
    var contacts = _unitOfWork.ContactRepository.GetQuery()
        .IncludeMultiple(x => x.Notes)
        .Where(x => contactIds.Any(y => y == x.Id))
        .ToList();  

    var noteModels = contacts.SelectMany(x => x.Notes.Select(n => GetNoteModel(n)));

    return noteModels.ToList();
}
```

The first statement causes a stack overflow if there are around 3000 records.  If I remove the .Where line, or if there are fewer records, it runs fine.

Is there a better way to do the .Any that won't cause a stack overflow?

As requested:

```
public static IQueryable<T> IncludeMultiple<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, 
    params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes) where T : class
{
    if (includes != null)
    {
        query = includes.Aggregate(query,
            (current, include) => current.Include(include));
    }

    return query;
}
```

Comment: How does `IncludeMultiple` method looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overlooked a very simple solution to this... using the .Contains function.

I modified my code to:

```
var contacts = _unitOfWork.ContactRepository.GetQuery()
    .IncludeMultiple(x => x.Notes)
    .Where(x => contactIds.Contains(x.Id))
    .ToList();
```

and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit on the size of the translated sql. So if there are a large number of `contactIds` the translated sql will be too large. A workaround is to split up the contactIds into smaller lists and combine the results. Something like this:

```
public List<NoteViewModel> GetAllPerContacts(List<long> contactIds)
{
   var query = _unitOfWork.ContactRepository.GetQuery().IncludeMultiple(x => x.Notes);

   IEnumerable<Contact> contacts = Enumerable.Empty<Contact>();

   long increment = 100;
   long groups = contactIds.Count / increment + 1;
   for(int i=0; i<groups; i++)
   {
     List<long> partialIds = contactIds.Skip(i*increment).Take(increment).ToList();
     contacts = contacts.Concat(query.Where(x => partialIds.Any(y => y == x.Id)).ToList());  
   }       

    var noteModels = contacts.SelectMany(x => x.Notes.Select(n => GetNoteModel(n)));

    return noteModels.ToList();
}
```

Comment: thanks for posting this.  There is actually a much simpler solution that I overlooked.  Using .Contains instead of .Any.